# Add horizontal accordion on button click

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add a horizontal accordion on click of a button.

I have used [this example](https://codepen.io/milesmanners/pen/QEQPjw?editors=1100) to create a horizontal accordion. This is working perfectly except for the fact that only 8 accordions can be added, I want as many of accordions as the user wants.

I've used the code above and then changed the accordion creation part on click of a button. The below code is in the link provided I don't want the max value to be 8. It should be any dynamic value.

```css
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .accslide {
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

li:nth-child(8):nth-last-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .accslide {
    width: calc(100% - 320px);
}
```

I want an output where the number of accordions in dynamic.How to modify the css part to work for any number of accordion added. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a way in css to get a dynamic counter for your tabs. You probably will have to also implement javascript for this.

Comment: You have to put a limit somewhere as the screensize will be an issue.

Comment: Yes. Aslam thank you.

Comment: yes thank you mrdeadsven. Is there a way I can add pagination for each accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified it by adding some JS. Hope this will help you in understanding. This will let you to add as many tabs you want. I have tried to keep it simple and easy. :)

```
let labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");

let width = 0;

labels.forEach(label => {
  width += label.clientWidth;
});

document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--label-width", width + "px");
```

Here is the codepen : https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/WNeOOPr

Comment: seeing your code, which btw nicely solved. I have a question concerning the max-tab variable in CSS. Would it be possible with javascript to adjust this variable to make it really dynamical? Or will you always be bound to set this variable yourself making it somewhat limited?

Comment: How is it limited? CSS is not magic, it need some information somewhere to work. My code is based on the example shared. If i would do it i will try to use CSS Flex :)

Comment: what I meant by limited is in your example the max-tab variable in CSS is set to 13 meaning if a user created 14 tabs it's not displayed because 13 is the max. So my question was if it is possible to change this max-tab variable in CSS dynamically with javascript? I hope this clears up my question don't really know how to describe it better with my knowledge of English :/

Comment: it was an unused variable :), i have removed it. (Sorry for commented code ) You can add as many tabs in the html and it will work accordingly. https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/WNeOOPr

Comment: Thanks aslam its working perfectly.  I have another doubt can you please help to look into that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924066/how-to-select-the-dropped-data-ui-based-on-the-value-present-in-the-dropped-item

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it using `CSS` only, refer this link https://codepen.io/AsfanShaikh/pen/bGbRoXO. In this example you can add accordion dynamically. But data is not wrapped in particular container. If you want to wrap data, you have to add some JS to make it working.

Comment: Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924066/how-to-select-the-dropped-data-ui-based-on-the-value-present-in-the-dropped-item can you have  a look into this.